# Elastic search create a dynamic field in response

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I am working on a Elasticsearch project. I want to get an additional column in response when an index is queried. Say for example, if I have an index with two columns `num1` and `num2`, when this index is queried it should respond with two column (`num1` and  `num2`) but also with additional column `add_result` (which is actually a addition of two columns). If I query it normally like below it would respond with just two columns

```
{
  query:{
    match_all : {}
  }
}
```

In my use case I have tried:

```
{
  "runtime_mappings": {
    "add_result": {
      "type": "double",
      "script": "emit(doc['file_count'].value + doc['follower_count'].value)"
    }
  },
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there are 2 ways:

#### 1. Using [runtime field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/runtime.html)

This feature is available since Elasticsearch 7.12. Simply make a `GET` request to the `_search` endpoint with the request body like this:

```json
{
  "runtime_mappings": {
    "add_result": {
      "type": "double",
      "script": "emit(doc['num1'].value + doc['num2'].value)"
    }
  },
  "fields": ["add_result", "num*"],
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  }
}
```

You need to explicitly specify that you want to get your runtime fields back in the [`fields`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-fields.html) parameter.

#### 2. Using [`script_field`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-fields.html#script-fields)

The request looks like this:

```json
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "fields": ["num*"],
  "script_fields": {
    "add_result": {
      "script": {
        "lang": "painless",
        "source": "doc['num1'].value + doc['num2'].value"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note that you still need to have the `fields` parameter, but you don't need to include your `script_field` (`add_result` in this case) in the `fields` parameter.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. I have tried with your solution in my use case. But I only see the existing fields, not run time added fields. I have updated question with my use case, please check

Comment: Oops, sorry, I forgot that you need to have the `fields` in the request body. Please check my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks it worked. Can I access related fields from other indices and perform logic and create a run time field. Not just addition of two nums.

Comment: AFAIK, it's not possible. You can search on multiple indices, but each index must have e.g. `num1` and `num2`, otherwise the query will throw an error.